# Looking for a terminal command to parse MacOSX dictionary data file

Tags: macos, dictionary, terminal, applescript, automator

**Problem**

MacOSX comes with dictionaries stored in `/Library/Dictionaries`. I would like to parse them to obtain dictionary results programmatically (via Terminal, AppleScript, or Automator). The dictionaries are MacOSX packages and all have a `Contents` folder that contains a file called `Body.data`. I would like to parse that file for a UTF-8 string (maybe Chinese character double bytes) and return the lines where the string is found.

I've tried the following, which is not returning any results:

```
find . -name 'Body.data' -exec grep -li '我' {} \;
```

When I search through the dictionary using the app interface I can find the appropriate text. My objective is to create a workflow service to translate selected Chinese text into the pinyin equivalents which are stored in the system/user dictionaries.

**Update**

The following worked for me based on the accepted answer:

Created and Archived a command line utility called `rdef` using Xcode with this code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        if(argc < 2)
        {
            printf("Usage: rdef <word to define>");

            return -1;
        }

        NSString * search =
        [NSString stringWithCString: argv[1] encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        CFStringRef def =
        DCSCopyTextDefinition(NULL,
                              (__bridge CFStringRef)search,
                              CFRangeMake(0, [search length]));

        NSString * output =
        [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Definition of <%@>: %@", search, (__bridge NSString *)def];

        printf("%s", [output UTF8String]);


    }
    return 0;
}
```

Added the following to my project frameworks:

[image: frameworks-added]

Performed a Build and then deployed manually using the steps below.

**To deploy:**

Right-clicked the Archived package and chose Show in Finder. Then Show Package Contents and drilled down product folder and copied the executable to `/local/usr/bin`. Now from a command prompt I can run the utility like so:

```
rdef 我|awk -F '\|' '{ gsub(/^ +| +$/, "", $2); print $2 }'
```

Please see the accepted answer below for extended references.

**NB:** 
The github for the utility can be found at https://github.com/mingsai/rdef.git

<del>Next I will just create a Service to call the utility from Automator against selected text.</del>

**Service Solution**

To pay it forward for the folks who've helped, especially @mklement0: here is the Solution for taking the command utility and converting it to a MacOSX service that can be used to translate Chinese characters to pinyin.

Create a new Automator Service file and make sure to select output replaces selected text.

[image: MacOSX Service - Convert Chinese to Pinyin]

**Automator Script details**

```
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin/: 
export PATH
LC_CTYPE=UTF-8
x=$1

for ((i=0;i<${#x};i++)); do rdef "${x:i:1}" | awk -F  '\|' 'BEGIN {ORS=" "}{ gsub(/^ | +?/, "", $2); if (length($2) > 0) print $2 ; exit}'; done
```

To make the Service "live" just delete the "Ask for Text" and save the service with name of your choice (e.g. Convert to Pinyin).

To use the revised service highlight any Chinese characters and right click the context menu then on the bottom under the Services menu select "Convert to Pinyin" ... (as indicated below)

**Usage**

[image: highlighted text]

[image: Service-Selection]

Produces this output

[image: output]

Hope that helps anyone with this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the update; I've since managed to simplify the `awk` command, see my updated answer. If you're up for it, it would be great if you also added the specifics of how you set up the Xcode project (what frameworks, includes, ...).

Comment: @mklement0 - The simplified version of the awk was picking up a stray pipe character. I've updated the question with the framework that I've added. This and the code which replaces the main function are all that were needed to make the rdef command work.

Comment: Thanks for the update. The second `__bridge` in your code should probably be `__bridge_transfer` so that ARC will take ownership and release string `def` for you (alternatively, at the end, call `CFRelease(def)`). As for the stray pipe: strange; perhaps `awk -F ' *[|] *' '{ print $2 }'` will work.

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks for pointing out the issue with the release. I have a small refinement that I'd ask for if you have a moment to spare. In some cases I have output that produces two sets of matches :i.e.rdef 都 produces -Definition of <都>: | dōu | all, both entirely (due to) each even
already
| dū |
capital city
metropolis
surname Du  and I would like to just grab only the first matching pipes. Any thoughts?TIA

Comment: If you're getting 2 output *lines* and you only want to process the 1st one, all you need to do is to add `; exit` after `print $2` in the `awk` program. What dictionary are you using? What comes closest on my machine is "Oxford Chinese Dictionary (Simplified Chinese-English)", but it doesn't produce the same output.

Comment: @mklement0 - I have about 6 Chinese dictionaries. That last comment fixed it! I'll be sure to share the service setup in my solution. I was trying grouping () and {1} to no avail.

Comment: Thank you for posting the Automator service details. As for `rdef` itself: please note that you've created a *generic* utility that searches whatever dictionaries the user happens to have selected in the Preferences dialog of Dictionary.app. Conversely, this implies that it'll only work with Chinese input if a Chinese dictionary is selected; I suggest you update the description on github. (Incidentally: what does the `r` in `rdef` stand for?)

Comment: @mklement0 - Will take another look at the github description. r is just "arbitrary", I'm sure that eventually it will mean something witty ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grep` operates on text files, but the `Body.data` files are not text files, unfortunately.

Your best bet is probably to create your own command-line utility in Xcode, as suggested here (sample code): https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2679911

Here's Apple's dictionary API documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/DictionaryServicesProgGuide/access/access.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006152-CH5-SW1

**Update**:

Assuming you've created a utility named `rdef` that returns something like `'Definition of <我>: | wǒ | I me my'`, use the following `awk` command to parse out the pinyin:

```
rdef "我" | awk -F ' *[|] *' '{ print $2 }'
```

---

Alternatively, if an online-based solution is an option, you could try a Google Translate-based solution.

At least in interactive use you get a pinyin transcription below the input field.

For instance, your example symbol is transcribed as "Wǒ":

http://translate.google.com/?text=%E6%88%91#zh-CN/en/%E6%88%91

Comment: Creating the command line util works well, now I just need to parse the output a bit more based on patterns returned from the dictionary. For example: 

rdef 我 

returns:
 
Definition of <我>: | wǒ |
I
me
my

Any thoughts on how to parse just the pinyin inside of the pipes from Terminal to achieve my initial objective. As you mentioned grep works on files.

Comment: @TommieC.: My pleasure; you simply need to pipe your lookup command to `awk` - see my updated example.

Answer (score 1):

I had a look in the `Chinese Simplified` and the `Oxford English Dictionary` and both have a `Contents` and `Body.data` file as you say. However, if I run

```
file Body.data
```

it just says `data` (rather than `ASCII` text, or `UTF-8`) - meaning that the file is binary rather than ASCII so grep and its friends are not going to work very well on them at all.

In case anyone is good at spotting a filetype from a hex dump, the files start off like this:

```
0000000      0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000
          \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0
*
0000100      c9a8    0106    0000    0000    ffff    ffff    0020    0000
         250 311 006 001  \0  \0  \0  \0 377 377 377 377      \0  \0  \0
0000120      0000    0000    0207    0000    ffff    ffff    ffff    ffff
          \0  \0  \0  \0  \a 002  \0  \0 377 377 377 377 377 377 377 377
0000140      8009    0000    8005    0000    8c22    0004    9c78    bddc
          \t 200  \0  \0 005 200  \0  \0   " 214 004  \0   x 234   ܽ  **
0000160      6c6b    db1b    2f7e    e416    49a6    349a    c5b8    902d
           k   l 033 333   ~   / 026 344 246   I 232   4 270 305   - 220
0000200      fda2    7134    7880    d4ef    2cb6    96d9    9dad    f673
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the insight. I've created a command line utility to handle one half of the issue but up voted your answer because it is very helpful.